# How to run docker image as a non-root user?

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker. When I run a docker images like ubuntu image by using the command,

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.04
```

By default, it is entering into the container as root like this. 
[image]

I searched regarding this, but I couldn't get any of how to start a docker image as a non root user as I'm completely a starter for this topic.

It would be great if someone explains with an example of how to run a docker image as a non root user.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the `docker run` command has the [`-u` parameter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) to allow you to specify a different user. In your case, and **assuming you have a user named `foo` in your docker image**, you could run:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -u foo ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

*NOTE:* The [`-u`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) parameter is the equivalent of the [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) instruction for Dockerfile.

Comment: do you mean add the user to the _docker_ group?

Comment: Do we need this user(uk) inside the docker container that we are running?  Otherwise how the image will identify that user? And as Adrian asked, are you referring to docker group?

Comment: Also it throws the error, `FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container acbd05873a7a22fdd538c931f9e6ee54184ff5f3ac6c281d732bbde1823cb731: [8] System error: Unable to find user uk`

Comment: @Udhayakumar; yes, you will need to have previously created the user in the image.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I mean _docker group_ not _vagrant group_. I edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: Please, DON'T add your user to the docker group. In fact, you should never, ever add any user to the docker group, unless in very very specific cases (that I can't think of yet). The docker group is root-equivalent. Once in the docker group, the user is able to perform privilege escalation for free. This is documented on the internet, and there's even a disclaimer in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user).

Comment: @Thomasleveil as per your solution, i have added the user in docker image and now i want to give this docker image to my client. so how the docker container will look for foo user in client machine ? do i need to create that user in my client environent ?

Answer (score 1):

This is admittedly hacky, but good for those quick little containers you start just to test something quickly:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

NAME=$1
IMG=$2

#UID=$(id -u)
USER=$(id -un)
GID=$(id -g)
GROUP=$(id -gn)

docker run -d -v /tmp:/tmp -v "/home/$USER:/home/$USER" -h "$NAME" --name "$NAME" "$IMG" /bin/bash

docker exec "$NAME" /bin/bash -c "groupadd -g $GID $GROUP && useradd -M -s /bin/bash -g $GID -u $UID $USER"
```

Full version of the script I use here:

https://github.com/ericcurtin/staging/blob/master/d-run

Comment: You can make this hack more formal by creating a new docker image based on the old one with the docker file containing the steps to correct the users configuration. Beware that on dockers based on busybox you have to use deluser and delgroup as there is no usermod.

Comment: That's true, it doesn't bother me though because these steps take milliseconds and I'd have to write a new dockerfile for each image I use this against (in my job, that's a lot of dockerfiles!)

Answer (score 0):

[udocker](https://github.com/indigo-dc/udocker) is a basic variant of docker which runs in user space:

> udocker is a basic user tool to execute simple docker containers in user space without requiring root privileges. Enables download and execution of docker containers by non-privileged users in Linux systems where docker is not available. It can be used to pull and execute docker containers in Linux batch systems and interactive clusters that are managed by other entities such as grid infrastructures or externally managed batch or interactive systems.

Answer (score -2):

It is not advisable to allow running docker without sudo as Docker has no auditing or logging built in, while sudo does.
If you want to give docker access to non-root users Red Hat recommends setting up sudo. 
Add an entry like the following to /etc/sudoers.

```
dwalsh        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker
```

Now, set up an alias in ~/.bashrc for running the docker command:

```
alias docker="sudo /usr/bin/docker"
```

Now when the user executes the docker command as non-root it will be allowed and get proper logging.

```
docker run -ti --privileged -v /:/host fedora chroot /host
```

Look at the journal or /var/log/messages.

```
journalctl -b | grep docker.*privileged
Aug 04 09:02:56 dhcp-10-19-62-196.boston.devel.redhat.com sudo[23422]:   dwalsh : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/dwalsh/docker/src/github.com/docker/docker ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/docker run -ti --privileged -v /:/host fedora chroot /host
```

Comment: The user is asking about running as a non-root user INSIDE the container, whereas you're talking about running as a non-root user outside the container. Very different questions.