# unable to run docker as non-root user?

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I have tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891010/how-to-run-docker-image-as-a-non-root-user) and it did NOT help.

I have created `jenkins` user and add it to docker group.

I have also switched the user in dockerFile (see below).

I started the container as following

`docker run -u jenkins -d -t -p 8080:8080 -v /var/jenkins:/jenkins -P docker-registry:5000/bar/helloworld:001`

The container starts fine. but when I look at the process, this is what I have

```
root     13575     1  1 09:34 ?        00:05:56 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
root     28409 13575  0 16:13 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 8080
```

The first one is daemon. so I guess it is ok to be root.
but the second one (which I have switched to jenkins user by issuing `sudo su jenkins`) is showing `root`. I started the docker as jenkins user. why this process belongs to root?

Here is my dockerfile

```
#copy jenkins war file to the container
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/1.643/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins


RUN useradd -d /home/jenkins -m -s /bin/bash jenkins
USER jenkins
ENV HOME /home/jenkins
WORKDIR /home/jenkins

# Maven settings
RUN mkdir .m2
ADD settings.xml .m2/settings.xml

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [""]
```

### EDIT2

I am certain the container the running. I could attach to the container.
I can also browse through web-ui of jenkins, which is only possible if the container has started without errors (jenkins run inside the container)

Here is my command inside the container

```
ps -ef | grep java
jenkins      1     0  7 19:29 ?        00:00:28 java -jar /opt/jenkins.war

ls -l /jenkins
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jan 11 18:54 jobs
```

But from the host file system, I see that the newly created "jobs" directory shows as user "admin"

```
ls -l /var/jenkins/
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin admin 4096 Jan 11 10:54 jobs
```

Inside the container, the jenkins process (war) is started by "jenkins" user. Once the jenkins starts, it writes to host file system under "admin" user.

Here is my entire dockerFile (NOTE: I don't use the one from here)

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum install -y sudo
RUN yum install -y -q unzip
RUN yum install -y -q telnet
RUN yum install -y -q wget
RUN yum install -y -q git

ENV mvn_version 3.2.2

# get maven
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/apache-maven-$mvn_version.tar.gz http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/$mvn_version/binaries/apache-maven-$mvn_version-bin.tar.gz
# verify checksum
RUN echo "87e5cc81bc4ab9b83986b3e77e6b3095 /tmp/apache-maven-$mvn_version.tar.gz" | md5sum -c

# install maven
RUN tar xzf /tmp/apache-maven-$mvn_version.tar.gz -C /opt/
RUN ln -s /opt/apache-maven-$mvn_version /opt/maven
RUN ln -s /opt/maven/bin/mvn /usr/local/bin
RUN rm -f /tmp/apache-maven-$mvn_version.tar.gz
ENV MAVEN_HOME /opt/maven

# set shell variables for java installation
ENV java_version 1.8.0_11
ENV filename jdk-8u11-linux-x64.tar.gz
ENV downloadlink http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12/$filename

# download java, accepting the license agreement
RUN wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" -O /tmp/$filename $downloadlink

# unpack java
RUN mkdir /opt/java-oracle && tar -zxf /tmp/$filename -C /opt/java-oracle/
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/java-oracle/jdk$java_version
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# configure symbolic links for the java and javac executables
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java $JAVA_HOME/bin/java 20000 && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac 20000

# copy jenkins war file to the container
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/1.643/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

#RUN useradd jenkins
#RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins
#RUN chmod -R 700 /home/jenkins
#USER jenkins

RUN useradd -d /home/jenkins -m -s /bin/bash jenkins
#RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins
USER jenkins
ENV HOME /home/jenkins
WORKDIR /home/jenkins

# Maven settings
RUN mkdir .m2
ADD settings.xml .m2/settings.xml
USER root
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins .m2
USER jenkins

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [""]
```

Answer (score 1):

The second process

```
root     28409 13575  0 16:13 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 8080
```

is NOT the process for your jenkins container but an internal process of the Docker engine to manage the network.

---

If, using the `ps` command, you cannot find the process which is supposed to run in your docker container, that means your docker container isn't running.

To ease figuring this out, start your container with the following command (adding `--name test`):

```
docker run --name test -u jenkins -d -t -p 8080:8080 -v /var/foo:/foo -P docker-registry:5000/bar/helloworld:001
```

Then type `docker ps`, you should see your container running. If not, type `docker ps -a` and you should see with which *exit code* it crashed.

If you need to know why it crashed, display its logs with `docker logs test`.

---

To look for the Jenkins process that runs from the official Jenkins docker image, use the following command:

```
ps aux | grep java
```

---

### EDIT

> why does the files seem to be owned by `admin` from the docker host point of view?

In your docker image, the `jenkins` user has *UID* `1000`. You can easily verify this with the following command: `docker run --rm -u jenkins --entrypoint /bin/id docker-registry:5000/bar/helloworld:001`

> uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins)

On your docker host, *UID* `1000` is for the `admin` user. You can verify this with `id admin` which in your case shows:

> uid=1000(admin) gid=1000(admin) groups=1000(admin),10(wheel)

The users which are available in a Docker container are not the ones from the docker host. However it might happen by coincidence that they have the same *UID*. This is why the `ls -l` command run on the docker host will tell you the files are owned by the `admin` user.

In fact **the files are owned by the user of *UID* `1000` which happens to be named `admin` on the docker host and `jenkins` on your docker image.**

Comment: I am certain the docker container is running, because I am able to attach to the container. Also, I could go browse jenkins UI which is only possible if the container has started (container runs jenkins)

Comment: and when you are using the `ps` command, have you used the `a` to display processes from all users (not only the current `root` user?). What does `ps aux | grep tini` shows?

Comment: the ps command I showed above is in host not container. are you asking me to run  `ps aux | grep tini` inside container?. also my question is why  the docker process, which I started as "jenkins" is not showing..

Comment: The ps command must be run on the Docker host, and not inside the container

Comment: I have updated "EDIT" section above. please have a look and give me your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: on your host, what is the output of `id admin`?

Comment: I get this `uid=1000(admin) gid=1000(admin) groups=1000(admin),10(wheel) `

Comment: yes. you are correct, I get this. `uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins)` . so what is the solution how to fix it? any idea?

Comment: There is no problem to fix, everything is behaving as you expect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100424/discussion-between-brain-storm-and-thomasleveil).

Comment: I get permission errors when jenkins write to file system (from UI). the jenkins job writes as admin user.
In the host filesystem, I have the directory /var/jenkins - this is readable and writable only for jenkins user. Now, the jenkins job try to write as admin user and it gets permission denied.