# How to run docker container as non-root user and how to share the docker image to others?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, root

I came across a scenario where I need to build a docker image which needs to run as a non-root user. To explain in detail, during docker build, I am trying to install a service which needs to be installed as non-root user. So i looked around some like [Link](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf) and [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891010/how-to-run-docker-image-as-a-non-root-user) which shows how to run a Docker container as non-root user. I am little confused on how to create a user in Dockerfile. I have used the below lines in dockerfile,

```
RUN useradd -r -u 1001 -g appuser appuser
USER appuser
```

I have successfully created the image and the container seems to be started as the appuser. But I need to provide this docker image to clients, so my question is,

1. Do I need to create the user appuser on my client machines?
2. How docker behaves in the client machine if I don't create any such users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to create the user appuser on my client machines?

The RUN command isn't creating it on your client machine, it's creating it on the container. In fact all instructions in your Dockerfile apply to the image being build and the container launched from it.

> How docker behaves in the client machine if I don't create any such users?

Same answer. Nothing is being installed on the client machine (apart from docker, which I assume is a given).

Comment: I got this confusion because some suggested to provide the uid of the user in dockerfile while creating the image. So i felt if i provide the uid, then the same uid should be available in the client machine